# change page borders for sidewaystable

Tags: margins, koma-script, rotating

I'm using KOMA script and have a long table that I put sideways. I want to increase the margins for the single page that contains the table. I can do this with `\KOMAoptions` or `\areaset` both have the same disadvantages:

1. lots of warnings about use of typeare outside of the header
2. still the footer is larger then the header. I think that looks odd, and I would like just to set a fixed maring (e.g. 2cm) on both sides and use the remaining space for the table.

Here an example:

```
    \documentclass[DIV=10,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{tabu}
    \usepackage{blindtext}


    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Test}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    \blindtext

    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \KOMAoptions{DIV=20}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \caption{A Table}
        \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X|c|c|c|}
            \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
            \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
            \blindtext & sample & sample & sample
        \end{tabu}
    \end{sidewaystable}
    \end{document}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You are thinking too complicated. Make a new document with your font settings, change the margins with geometry, include the pdf in your document using `pdfpages`. Don't forget to set the counter to an appropriate value.

Comment: That sounds feasible, but then I can't use glossary entries, cross-references, citations in the table caption, .... So I think it would be better to put everything in one document

Comment: A similar question popped up on TeXwelt, it might help you: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/14903/abbildung-auf-a3-seite-und-caption-auf-a4-seite-davor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following, which is stolen from [saputello](http://texwelt.de/wissen/benutzer/16/saputello) on [TeXwelt](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/14903/abbildung-auf-a3-seite-und-caption-auf-a4-seite-davor).

```
\documentclass[DIV=10,headsepline,footsepline,captions=tableabove]{scrbook}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\AtBeginDocument{
    \storeareas\NormalArea
%\KOMAoptions{headinclude=false,footinclude=false,DIV=20,}
    \KOMAoptions{headinclude=false}
    \areaset{180mm}{280mm}
    \storeareas\LargeArea
    \NormalArea
    \newcommand*{\switchtoNormal}{\clearpage\NormalArea}%
    \newcommand*{\switchtoLarge}{\clearpage\LargeArea}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[9]

\switchtoLarge
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \caption{A Table}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X|c|c|c|}
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{sidewaystable}

\switchtoNormal

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

The warning about doing this stuff in the preamble remains tough.

---

If you want to get completely rid of the warning, you have your own idea how the page is supposed to look like anyway, use geometry for the large page. Keyword now: `usegeometry`

```
\documentclass[usegeometry,DIV=10,headsepline,footsepline,captions=tableabove]{scrbook}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[9]

\newgeometry{margin=.9cm}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \caption{A Table}
    \begin{tabu} to \linewidth {|X|c|c|c|}
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
        \blindtext & sample & sample & sample \\
    \end{tabu}
\end{sidewaystable}

\restoregeometry

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext[9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I can use both, `koma-script` and `geometry`. But why do you need `usegeometry`?

Comment: Because otherwise, you cannot use them together.

Comment: @Jonas I should add, that this is undocumented yet and can change everytime.

Comment: Sth else about this solution: `\newgeometry` requires a `\clearpage`. This prevents the table from floating. Is there any way to let the table float despite changing the geometry?

Comment: @Jonas A sidewaystable cannot float. It just can't. Nothing to do with geometry.

Comment: Yes it can float. If you use your MWE from this post and just remove the `chapter`. Then complie it once with the `newgeometry`/`restoregeometry` and once without and you see that the table floats without the new geometry.

Comment: @Jonas You are right, they can float.

Comment: @Jonas Thinking about it, make that a new follow-up question. Don't forget to add a link to this question/answer, though.

Comment: posted it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352412/

Comment: already seen, already upvoted ;-)